# Avoid multiple definitions of same function inside a Python package

Tags: python

Consider the following `python` package structure

```
 working_directory/
-- test_run.py
-- mypackge/
---- __init__.py
---- file1.py
---- file2.py
```

Inside `file1.py` and `file2.py` I have defined function `func1()` and `func2()`, respectively. Now, to run, func2() needs to use func1() and I could simply import func1() in file2.py with `from file1 import func1`, but since the whole package will be loaded together I could probably use `func1()` from the namespace it was already loaded in the first place. How can I do it in general to avoid having func1() defined in multiple places?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There wouldn't be multiple definitions. They would all refer to the same loaded module.

When you import a module Python first checks `sys.modules` if the module has already been loaded. If it is found it returns the already loaded module. This doesn't change no matter how the module is imported.

Comment: But while at `test_run.py` I can access the function through `mypackage.file1.func1()` and also through `mypackage.file2.func1()`. Can't this be avoided?

Comment: So you want to be unable to do `mp.file2.func1()`?

Comment: Yes. I could "hide" it by importing it as `_func1` in `file2.py`, but wouldn't there be a better solution?

Comment: Python has no notion of "private". The best and recommended way is to prefix it with an underscore, this tells other users the intent of it. If `file2` isn't needed throughout the use of `mp` then you could always `del`ete it. The more complicated route would be to import it and use it like `sys.modules["file2"].func1()`. However I don't recommend it, and instead recommend to use a prefixed underscore.

Answer (score 0):

The original question sounds like you are worried there are multiple definitions to shared modules. I think @Vallentin has already answered that the module won't be 'loaded' multiple times. Just be sure to use a consistent naming convention if the modules are aliased in your package, for your own sanity. In other words, if you alias `mymodule1` as `mod1` in one file, you should probably use the same alias in other files.

However, from your comments, it sounds like you really want to create an api to `mypackage`, with public functions from `module1` accessible to the user's code `test_run.py` (and perhaps from the interactive interpreter), while preventing functions in `module2` from being directly accessible to the user. Here's one option for that.

**Nest the "private" code in sub-directories within `mypackage`:**
The nice thing is that you can put modules you want to be directly accessible within the first level of the package. Supporting modules can be placed in subdirectories. For example:

```
working_directory/
    test_run.py
    mypackage/
        __init__.py
        module1.py
        utilities/
            __init__.py
            module2.py
```

```
# ./mypackage/__init__.py
# Use `__all__` to list modules imported by `from package_name import *` 
# and used as `module_name.func_name()`
__all__ = ['module1']
```

```
# ./mypackage/module1.py
# Import modules/funcs from the utilities directory:
from utilities.module2 import func2
```

```
# Usage:
from mypackage import * 
module1.func2()
# OR
from mypackage import module1
module1.func2()
# OR
import mypackage as mp
mp.module1.func2()
# BUT you cannot do:
import mypackage as mp
mp.module2.func2()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'module2'
```

Note that nested directories can still be imported as long as the user digs for them using the dot notation: `mypackage.utilities.module2.func2()`, so they aren't really "private". However, they won't be directly accessible from the first level when `mypackage` is imported.